# Finding a cell in devexpress datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I'm new to DevExpress GridControl.
I need to find a particular cell in the grid and then do something with it's value.
How do I go about this please?

In the grid's `Loaded` method, I tried using `myGrid.FindRowByValue("ProductType","ABC"),` but always gives a negative number.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code you can try

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.DataRowCount; i++) {
    object b = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "FieldName");
    if (b != null && b.Equals(<someValue>)){
        gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = i;
        return;
    }
}
```

you can go to this link for more details.

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q132599/get-row-by-cell-value

Answer (score 0):

Unlike XtraGrid, the DXGrid for WPF does not provide the `DataRowCount` property - that is why we suggested checking the GridControl's ItemsSource. On the other hand, our grid has the VisibleRowCount property, which will be useful in some scenarios.

To accomplish this task, iterate through visible grid rows manually as shown below.

```
void MoveFocusToLast(GridControl grid, string fieldName, object value) {
    for (int i = grid.VisibleRowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var handle = grid.GetRowHandleByVisibleIndex(i);
        var currentValue = grid.GetCellValue(handle, fieldName);
        if (currentValue != null && currentValue.Equals(value)) {
            grid.View.FocusedRowHandle = handle;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

> Grid also provides the [FindRowByValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridControl_FindRowByValuetopic) method, which allows you to
>   find a row by a specific cell value. This method returns the handle of
>   the corresponding row, and you can make that row visible by setting
>   the [FocusedRowHandle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataViewBase_FocusedRowHandletopic) property or calling [ScrollIntoView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataViewBase_ScrollIntoViewtopic). I
>   have prepared a sample demonstrating this approach.

**See Also:**
[Traversing Rows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6122)
[Find Row](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T367072/find-row)
[Get RowHandle from a cell value](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T281027/get-rowhandle-from-a-cell-value)